# SQL query to display a "total column" across several rows

Tags: sql, db2

assume I have the following table

```
claim_id | person_id | age_category | amount
--------------------------------------------
       1 |         1 |        adult |  10.00
       1 |         2 |        adult |  10.00
       1 |         3 |     juvenile |   8.00
       1 |         4 |        child |   5.00
       2 |         5 |        adult |  15.00
       3 |         6 |        adult |  12.00
       3 |         7 |        child |   6.00
     ...
     100 |       250 |        child |   7.00
```

So several people could belong to the same claim.
What I already managed to achieve is such a result table:

```
category | total people |     amount
------------------------------------
adult    |          150 | 300'000.00
juvenile |           20 |  40'000.00
child    |           80 | 160'000.00
```

with the following query:

```
select 
    age_category as "category"
    count(*) as "total people",
    sum(amount) as "amount"
from
    my_table
group by
    age_category
```

Is there a way how I can count the number of claims and display it in the same result table? E.g. something like:

```
category | total claims | total people |     amount
---------------------------------------|-----------
adult    |          100 |          150 | 300'000.00
juvenile |              |           20 |  40'000.00
child    |              |           80 | 160'000.00
```

Thanks for any hints!

P.S.: I am using DB2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select 
    age_category as "category",
    COUNT(distinct claim_id ) as "total_claims", --  <-- add this line 
    count(*) as "total people",
    sum(amount) as "amount"

from
    my_table
group by
    age_category
```

EDIT:

AS per your comment, use this query

```
select 
    age_category as "category",
    case when age_category='adult' then COUNT(distinct claim_id ) end 
                                                         as "total_claims" , 
    count(*) as "total people",
    sum(amount) as "amount"

from
    my_table
group by
    age_category
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ec00/2)

Comment: Thanks, I have thought about that already, but the result is not quite correct as it would output claim counts for 'juvenile' and 'child' as well. My problem is that these counts should not be listed as 'child'/'juvenile' are always part of an adult's claim.

Comment: It's just a copy-paste of older answers.

Comment: @hgulyan: Are you serious..?? Your answer and my answer is same.. and I  answered 11 min ago.. where as u 5 min ago...

Comment: Oh, didn't see, that you've updated your answer. Now it's right.

Comment: @hgulyan: If I have updated my Answer, It would have showed as "edited"

Comment: Hi Joseph, is it possible to display the 'count' for 'juvenile' and 'child' as 'null or '0' and just display the count for adults (as an adult is the owner of a claim)?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    age_category as "category",
    sum(case when amount>0 then 1 else 0 end ) as "total claims",
    count(*) as "total people",
    sum(amount) as "amount"
from
    my_table
group by
    age_category
```

Comment: Thanks, I have thought about that already, but the result is not quite correct as it would output claim counts for 'juvenile' and 'child' as well. My problem is that these counts should not be listed as 'child'/'juvenile' are always part of an adult's claim.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use count(DISTINCT ):

```
select 
    age_category as "category"
    count(*) as "total people",
    sum(amount) as "amount",
    count(distinct claim_id) as "total_claims"
from
    my_table
group by
    age_category
```

or also try to use this:

```
select t.*,
(select count(*) from

(select distinct claim_id from my_table 
   where my_table.age_category=t.category) as d
 ) as "total_claims"
from
(
select 
    age_category as "category",
    count(*) as "total people",
    sum(amount) as "amount"
from
    my_table
group by
    age_category
  ) as t
```

Comment: this doesn't count the claims but sums up the claim id's